# All inputs give (more or less) the same output for this untrained neural network with randomly initialised weights

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, neural-network

Newbie to neural networks here.

The following code is what I've done so far, I haven't written the back propagation function yet. All the network does is give an output for an input with randomly generated weights in the range [-1/input_neurons ^ 0.5, 1/input_neurons ^ 0.5]

So this is a totally untrained network, but the results I'm seeing now are not normal I believe. Regardless of the image inputted, the output is incredibly similar so the neural network recognizes only a specific number every time.

I've fiddled with the number of hidden neurons and layers, but increasing them only makes the issue worse (output has no differences).

The input is an image, 28 x 28, each pixel having a value in the range 0 to 255. Initially the values going into my sigmoid function were too large saturating it so I divide by 255 to get inputs in the range 0 to 1.

I did read some similar questions here but the answers didn't help all too much, any ideas as to why this happens?

```
class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.input_neurons = 784
        self.hidden_neurons = 128
        self.hidden_layers = 2
        self.output_neurons = 10
        self.weights = {}
        self.layers = {}
        self.bias = {}

    def generate_weights_and_bias(self):
        self.weights["0"] = np.random.uniform(low=(-1/(self.input_neurons ** 0.5)), high=(1/(self.input_neurons ** 0.5)), size=(self.hidden_neurons, self.input_neurons))

        for weight in range(1, self.hidden_layers):
            self.weights[str(weight)] = np.random.uniform(low=(-1/(self.hidden_neurons ** 0.5)), high=(1/(self.hidden_neurons ** 0.5)), size=(self.hidden_neurons, self.hidden_neurons))

        self.weights[str(self.hidden_layers)] = np.random.uniform(low=(-1/(self.output_neurons ** 0.5)), high=(1/(self.output_neurons ** 0.5)), size=(self.output_neurons, self.hidden_neurons))

        for hidden_layer in range(self.hidden_layers):
            self.bias[str(hidden_layer)] = np.zeros((self.hidden_neurons, 1))

        self.bias[str(self.hidden_layers)] = np.zeros((self.output_neurons, 1))

    def feed_forward(self):
        self.layers["hidden0"] = sigmoid((self.weights.get("0") @ self.layers.get("input")) + self.bias.get("0"))

        for layer in range(1, self.hidden_layers):
            self.layers["hidden" + str(layer)] =  sigmoid((self.weights.get(str(layer)) @ self.layers.get("hidden" + str(layer - 1))) + self.bias.get(str(layer)))

        self.layers["output"] =  sigmoid((self.weights.get(str(self.hidden_layers)) @ self.layers.get("hidden" + str(self.hidden_layers - 1))) + self.bias.get(str(self.hidden_layers)))

    def test(self):
        images = IMAGES # list of bytearrays which contain 784 bytes each in the range 0 to 255
        labels = LABELS # list of digits 0 to 9

        total_images = len(images)
        successfully_recognised = 0

        for image in enumerate(images):
            self.layers["input"] = np.array(image[1]).reshape(self.input_neurons, 1) / 255
            self.feed_forward()

            print(labels[image[0]], self.layers.get("output"))
            if labels[image[0]] == self.layers.get("output").argmax():
                print(f"{labels[image[0]]} was recognised successfully")
                successfully_recognised += 1

        print(f"Accuracy is {(successfully_recognised / total_images * 100)}%")
        print(f"{successfully_recognised} images successfully recognised of {total_images}")


def sigmoid(x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    network = Network()
    network.generate_weights_and_bias()
    network.test()
```

Comment: All of your inputs are in the same orthant. Have you tried subtracting 0.5 from the inputs to put them in the range [-0.5, 0.5]?

Comment: @SubhaneilLahiri Just tried it, didn't have any effect.

Comment: I have the same problem..